# Enforcing side effects in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, code-analysis

Is there a tool that enables you to annotate functions/methods as "pure" and then analyzes the code to test if said functions/methods are side effect free ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Python world, the question doesn't make much sense since objects have so much say in what happens in a function call.

For example, how could you tell if the following function is pure?

```
def f(x):
   return x + 1
```

The answer depends on what *x* is:

```
>>> class A(int):
        def __add__(self, other):
            global s
            s += 1
            return int.__add__(self, other)

>>> def f(x):
        return x + 1

>>> s = 0
>>> f(A(1))
2
>>> s
1
```

Though the function *f* looks pure, the add operation on *x* has the side-effect of incrementing *s*.

Comment: What you *can* do is check if `f` is pure **assuming** `type(x) == int`. Because Python is dynamically typed, you would have to add type annotations manually, though.